# What were Leibniz's concrete contributions to the life sciences?

Tags: biographical-details

I read at many places that Leibniz made a lot of contributions to biology, anatomy, medicine, paleontology and other related life sciences, but I couldn't find concrete contributions of him to these fields. I'm not looking for philosophical remarks that have far reaching meaning (for example, his distinction between organic bodies and "artificial" machines) but rather for more practical contributions. I'm far from being an expert to Leibniz's writings and that is why i'm asking this question. I'm very curious to discover Leibniz's wisdom so if someone has references, please write them down.

Answer (score 1):

See:

- Justin Smith,[Divine Machines: Leibniz and the Sciences of Life](https://books.google.it/books?id=IcqhWpzRJ9MC&pg=PA16) (2011), page 16:

> Looking at his career as a whole, we may say that Leibniz’s biological interests lie at the center of at least three core issues in his philosophy:
>
> > 1. The problem of the structure and motion of the physical world, both of living entities as normally understood as well as of apparently lifeless things.
> > 2. The problem of coming into being, or generation.
> > 3. Species.

Of course, no "practical" contribution.

See also Leibniz's contribution to paleontology, with his principal work on this subject, [Protogaea](https://books.google.it/books?id=_QFdQJznrQsC&printsec=frontcover), unpublished in his lifetime.

Comment: Unfortunately, as is always the case with google books, i'm unable to read continuosly at the book. I have to ask you if you think it's a good book, because if it's a good book i'll buy it.

Comment: @user2554 - you can browse the [ToC](https://books.google.it/books?id=IcqhWpzRJ9MC&pg=PR5): of course, is not concerned with modern scientific biology, but with "life science" in the time of Descrtes and Leibniz, when Aristotelian "natural science" was still the *paradigm* outside the newly-born mechanics.

Comment: What is ToC? if you know a way to read the whole book than explain it to me. As for my question, perhaps i should focus it: are there any anticipations by leibniz of modern concepts? for example, i'm pretty sure that in some of his writings leibniz anticipated the discovery of the DNA - when he concludes in his writings that each tiny part of an organic body contains the information about the whole body, he actually reasons from first principles a conclusion about the way organic bodies are organized, and in this case reasons that the hereditary material is present in each cell of the body.

Comment: @user2554 - Table of Contents.

Comment: Mauro ALLEGRANZA - I have to ask you another question. Can you recommend me on a good biography of leibniz? i dont have any english biography of him. I'm less interested at his philosophical ideas but more at his mathematical, scientific and technological contributions. From a brief survey of the literature i was most impressed of the book : The cambridge companion to leibniz. But do you know a better book?

Comment: @user2554 - The Cambridge Companions are always very useful. For Leibniz, see E.J. Aiton, *Leibniz: A Biography* (1985) and Maria Rosa Antognazza, [Leibniz: An Intellectual Biography](https://books.google.it/books?id=DQ4qEpjVomMC) (2011).

Comment: Mauro ALLEGRANZA, the second biography you gave seems to me like a biography who focuses much on his philosophical output. The first one look to me more interesting from the aspect of technology, science and mathematics. Can you find a table of contents of the first biography?

Comment: @user2554, you've asked quite a few interesting questions and have made a number of follow-up requests for information.  But I've also noticed that, to date, you have never once upvoted any response you've received at this exchange.  Are you still waiting for a satisfactory response on all of the questions you've asked so far?

Comment: Mark Yasuda -  Sorry, i'm new to this site and dont know it well. I've got satisfactory answers to some of my question, but i didn't know i need to do something about that.

Comment: For an evaluation of Leibniz's mathematical contribution as far as infinitesimal calculus is concerned, you could read [this article](http://dx.doi.org/10.1086/685645).